# VS code error in deubug - [debugger-for-chrome] Error processing "launch" : 'Log.enable' wasn't found

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

I am getting this error during debugging of React application in Visual Studio Code, Tried to find in several places but couldn't get an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It was google chrome browser version issue , i had version 45. Updated to version 68 , now it is working.